# Query com LeftJoins usando GroupBy os Includes não são realizados EF.Core C#

Tags: c#, expressões-lambda, entity-framework-core

Preciso realizar uma query com o entity framework onde tenho tenho uma entidade Oferta e nela tenho vários Cartões(Entidade).

Na query estou realizando o include do cartão, e usando o SelectMany para realizar um filtro para pegar apenas os cartões ativos da oferta. Mas quando realizado o GroupBy na query o EF Core não está realizando os includes.

Obs: Como tenho dois cartões na oferta, preciso realizar o group by para não repetir a oferta, e quando não uso o group by a oferta vem com os includes mas com a oferta duplicada.

> Entidade (Oferta)

```
public class Oferta : EntityBase
{
    public Oferta()
    {
        Cartoes = new HashSet<OfertaCartao>();     

    }

    public long? OfertaId { get; set; }
    public bool IndicadorSituacao { get; set; }
    public string DescricaoOferta { get; set; }        
    public DateTime DataVigenciaInicial { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DataVigenciaFinal { get; set; }        
    public IdentificacaoEtapaFluxo IdentificacaoPac { get; set; }
    public IdentificacaoSegmentoProspect IdentificacaoSegmentoProspect { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<OfertaCartao> Cartoes { get; set; }        

}
```

> Entidade (Cartao)

```
public class OfertaCartao : EntityBase
{
    public OfertaCartao()
    {
        OfertaCartaoBeneficios = new HashSet<OfertaCartaoBeneficio>();
    }

    public long CartaoId { get; set; }
    public long? OfertaId { get; set; }
    public virtual Oferta Oferta { get; set; }
    public IdentificacaoEtapaFluxo IdentificacaoPac { get; set; }
    public IdentificacaoSegmentoProspect IdentificacaoSegmentoProspect { get; set; }
    public long? TermoCondicaoId { get; set; }
    public virtual TermoCondicao TermoCondicao { get; set; }
    public string DescricaoCartao { get; set; }
    public string TextoAnuidadeCartao { get; set; }
    public bool IndicadorSituacao { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataVigenciaInicial { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DataVigenciaFinal { get; set; }
    public string IdentificacaoArquivoPoliticaIsencaoDeTarifas { get; set; }        
    public IdentificacaoBandeiraCartao? IdentificacaoBandeiraCartao { get; set; }
    public IdentificacaoModalidadeCartao? IdentificacaoModalidadeCartao { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<OfertaCartaoBeneficio> OfertaCartaoBeneficios { get; set; }
}
```

> Query

```
        var result = _aberturaDeContasContext.Ofertas
            .Include(x => x.Cartoes)                    
            .Where(where)
            .Where(x => x.IndicadorSituacao)
            .WhereInVigencia()
            .SelectMany(sm => sm.Cartoes.Where(w => w.IndicadorSituacao).DefaultIfEmpty(), (key, inner) => key)
            .GroupBy(x => x)                
            .Select(x => x.First());
```

Comment: é EntityFrameworkCore ou a versão `6.x`?

Comment: É o EntityFrameworkCore

Comment: Se você carregar somente as ofertas e depois da a carga da relação não seria mais simples?

Comment: Mas pensando em performance, isso é inviável certo? Essa é até uma questão simples, mas gostaria de saber como resolver isso realmente realizando um SQL puro com o EFCore.

Comment: Porque que inviável? desempenho, não é assim cara que funciona EFCore, claro se pode fazer a SQL pura ele te dá essa opção, mas, eu carregaria Ofertas e depois com `Context.Entry(entity).Collection` carregaria as relações !!! não tem perca de desempenho!

Comment: Perca de desempenho é a sua expressão que faz um monte de coisa e causa ai sim lentidão...

Comment: @VirgilioNovic, Poderia me dar um exemplo de como realizar esse join e com filtro no join?

Comment: Me explica o que você quer trazer ofertas e ??? me explica o resultado.

Comment: Preciso de uma query para buscar as ofertas ativas, e realizar left join com a tabela ofertacartao(onde a oferta pode ter vários cartões) EX:   SELECT * 
  FROM ACDTOFE OFERTA
  LEFT JOIN ACDTOFC OFERTACARTAO ON 
  OFERTA.ID_OFER = OFERTACARTAO.ID_OFER 
  AND
  OFERTA.ID_PAC = OFERTACARTAO.ID_PAC 
  AND
  OFERTA.ID_SEGM_PROSP = OFERTACARTAO.ID_SEGM_PROSP
  AND 
  OFERTACARTAO.IC_SIT_OFER_CRTO = 1
  WHERE
  OFERTA.IC_SIT_OFER = 1

Comment: usa o FromSql é melhor no seu caso ... sendo que você tem um junção com vários filtros dentro ...